# Powershell - importing data from file

Tags: powershell, csv, import

I'm new to Powershell and I've got a problem. I have this code below, after  execution it prompts for a group name in AD and then exports all members of this group into .csv file. How to change this to import multiple group names from .csv file?

```
param
(   
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)]
    [String]$GroupName
)

$GFile = New-Item -type file -force "C:\Scripts\GroupDetails.csv"

$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like $GroupName} | Select-Object Name

ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {

    Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | Select-Object samaccountname | Out-File $GFile -append
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this would help you:

```
Param (
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
    [String]$ImportFile = 'S:\Test\Input_Test\GroupNames.txt',
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
    [String]$SaveFolder = 'S:\Test\Input_Test'
)

$Groups = Get-Content $ImportFile

ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | 
            Out-File -LiteralPath (Join-Path $SaveFolder "$Group.txt")
}
```

You can fill the file `GroupNames.txt` with the groups you want and it will create one file for each group.

**Content GroupNames.txt:**

```
Group 1
Group 2
```

If you want to go a bit more advanced, you can create a function like this:

```
Function Export-ADGroupMembersToFile {
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [String]$ImportFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [String]$SaveFolder
    )

    $Groups = Get-Content $ImportFile

    $OutFile = Join-Path $SaveFolder "Groups_$(Get-Date -F 'yyyyMMddHHmm').txt"
    Write-Verbose  "Output will be saved to file '$OutFile'"

    ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
        Write-Verbose "GroupName: $Group"
        "`n", $Group, ('-'*40) | Out-File -LiteralPath $OutFile -Append

        $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive | 
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

        foreach ($M in $Members) {
            Write-Verbose "Adding user $M"
            Out-File -InputObject $M -LiteralPath $OutFile -Append
        } 
    }
}

Export-ADGroupMembersToFile -ImportFile 'S:\Test\Input_Test\GroupNames.txt' -SaveFolder 'S:\Test\Input_Test' -Verbose
```

This will output one file that contains all the GroupNames.

Comment: Answer updated by your request. If you remove the `-Verbose` switch, you don't see the output. I guess a function is always better. It makes things portable. If you would like to change it and want to stop somewhere within a function, use `F9` in the PowerShell ISE to set a `PSBreakPoint`. And it allows you to check the contents of variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot DarkLite1! The second one was a great base.  After some modifications  it  works like a charm:)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it helped you out. And remember, keep on exploring! You get better at it every time you play with it :)